# Type assertion with Type or Interface

Tags: typescript

How to do this? :

```
type Brain = ...;
type Body = ...;

f = (part: Brain| Body) => {
 // An error occurs here: 
 // Brain' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
 if (typeof part === Brain) {
  // do something...
 } 

}
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type aliases and interfaces only exist at compile-time, so you can't really perform any run-time check based on them.

Depending on what you need you can use one of several approaches:

1. **Very Strict:** Use something [typescript-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-is) to allow a plugin to generate some extra code to perform exact type interface checking.
2. **Strict enough**: Use a custom type guard to check the value is of a specific type
3. **Lax**: Use the `in` operator as a type guard.

The simplest approach is using the `in` operator to check for the presence of a property that only exists in one of the types:

```
type Brain = { brainSize: number, eyeColor: string };
type Body = { weight: number };

const f = (part: Brain | Body) => {
  if ('brainSize' in part) {
    part.brainSize //ok
    part.eyeColor // also ok  
  } else {
    part.weight //ok
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=2&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwLACgYE8zDgISgEMBLAOzgF5E4AjY8gZRIC9gAuOMgVwFtbgUADRxgWYAGEIAG2icAzjCjkA5igDcGbLgIQAJlio0A7sBIqAFjE49+gjRgwBjCGUVwAZkYAUYIrE5CUgoAH10DAEoqAD5EDDg4Ei9vAHJ6YOY2FMSKP1gohHiEuDyYADp0plY8AHoaiABrIoTSsrFJGWg4OrgiaXkIOEaEouRRfrxC9GKS-3LTcytu+qbplAxkIA)

If you want to be extra sure, you can use a custom type guard to manually check all the properties of a the interface:

```
type Brain = { brainSize: number, eyeColor: string };
type Body = { weight: number };

function isBrain(part: unknown): part is Brain {
  let maybeBrain = part as Brain
  return maybeBrain
    && typeof maybeBrain.brainSize === "number"
    && typeof maybeBrain.eyeColor === "string"
}
const f = (part: Brain | Body) => {
  if (isBrain(part)) {
    part.brainSize //ok
    part.eyeColor // also ok  
  } else {
    part.weight //ok
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=2&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwLACgYE8zDgISgEMBLAOzgF5E4AjY8gZRIC9gAuOMgVwFtbgUADRxgWYAGEIAG2icAzjCjkA5igDcGbLgIQAJlio0A7sBIqAFjE49+gjRgwAzbmQDGMEhAol5hUmQAFGBEsJyuANZkEMZkAJScIbBwvgQMFAgYcHDSwPC8RFgC-uRGSfBE8mkBWXBQedxQFAVFwCVktdkAZF1w2sAQTnAtxekAdPQBzGxUlNQARLYCUPOdcD19OANDI23jYpIy0LMLispkKqvoaOhu3opwQ9TBodbVpQA+ugZxVAB8iFqJCGgV87ResDiv0y6Gy2XKE3S0zwAHoURAImsEQcpLIoHA0XAiNJ5BA4BjsrVkKISXgYXC4AjTOYrAT0ZjYSgMMggA)

The strictest option is to use `typescript-is` in order to generate code similar to out type guard, but this implies replacing the default compiler with `ttypescript` which I personally don't recommend.

Comment: Is there are ways to assert type which consist of string? e.g: type Test = "T" | "E" | "S" | "T";   f("T"); f(str) => str === T;

Comment: @JillAndMe unusre what you are asking, if `str` is of type `Test` or `string` `str ==="T"` will narrow the value if use in an `if`